# Workflow and Organic Groups. How can you email the next state changer when content is posted?

Tags: 6, workflows, actions, organic-groups

I would like to notify someone with editor permissions that a user has posted content in the workflow.  I found a token for the current state updating user ([workflow-current-state-updating-user-mail]]), but nothing for the next user in line.

I've seen reference to using rules to send email to all users of a particular role, but I need something more like 'send email to users of a role who belong to the current group'.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this by writing a module to create a custom token from a field added to the group_node_form.  I followed this tutorial, making adaptations for organic groups:  http://rbayliss.net/story/creating-tokens-drupal-6